# Trigger Jenkins downstream job when upstream push to Git Master only

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

As testing team, I wish to only run my Test when Developer is merged their code to Master. However, in Jenkins, my job is triggered everytime Developers push in their code no matter on Branches or Master.

I am using the `Build after other projects are built` as `Build Triggers`, and I cant see any option for me to filter the branch like what in TeamCity.

Can anyone help?